# Use case of CURRENT_SESSION

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the use case of current_session. Where are we going to use alphanumeric value [current_session](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_session.html)

Answer (score 1):

The SESSION_ID from CURRENT_SESSION() appears in QUERY_HISTORY*(), allowing you to associate queries with a particular session.

It also appears in SHOW TRANSACTIONS, and in the Snowflake UI Sessions tab.

And you can use it with SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION() and SYSTEM$CANCEL_ALL_QUERIES().

And lastly you can use it in your own logging to tie activity to a particular session.

Answer (score 0):

Also each worksheet in your snowflake will be independent session. You can work independently without interrupting another session in snowflake.